# Accessing 2 elements of the same array in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to assign 2 values from 2 different addresses in my array in VHDL, but somehow they always return to me a wrong value (most of the time, zero). I tested it with only 1 address and 1 data output it returned the correct value.

```
    architecture Behavioral of registerFile is
    type reg_type is array (31 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    signal REG : reg_type := (x"00000031", x"00000030", x"00000029", x"00000028", x"00000027", x"00000026", x"00000025", x"00000024", x"00000023", x"00000022", x"00000021", x"00000020",x"00000019",x"00000018", x"00000017", x"00000016", x"00000015", x"00000014", x"00000013", x"00000012", x"00000011", x"00000010", x"00000009", x"00000008", x"00000007",x"00000006", x"00000005", x"00000004", x"00000003", x"00000004", x"00000001", x"00000000");
begin
process(clk)
begin
    if clk'event and clk='1' then
        if ENABLE = '1' then
            if readReg = '1' then -- read from register
                DATAone <= REG(conv_integer(ADDRone));
                DATAtwo <= REG(conv_integer(ADDRtwo));
            else
                REG(conv_integer(ADDRone)) <= DATAone;
                REG(conv_integer(ADDRtwo)) <= DATAtwo;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Would appreciate some help, I tried googling but it's all either multidimensional arrays or only accessing 1 element at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Could you post the entity declaration? 2) How are you driving the inputs to the module? 3) What exactly is happening in the simulator?

Comment: DATAone and DATAtwo are used for both output from read and into for write, so the read value is also the value written back... this looks odd; I would expect a register file to have separate data ports for read and write.  It may be OK, but please give some more background on the requirement, and also post the entity declaration so it is easier to get the whole picture.

Comment: Thanks. It has been working on the simulation but not working on the FPGA. But after changing this it works. I think I have missed this out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is synthesizable in most fabric. You could create two copies of the reg array and index into each of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to implement a quad-port memory. Anyway, even if your register file is not exactly a 4-port memory, it probably can be implemented around one.

Altera has an example of such a memory in their [Advanced Synthesis Cookbook](http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/stx_cookbook.pdf). The picture below shows the relevant part:

[image: Altera Simple Quad Port RAM Example]

If use the Altera example files, it will instantiate Altera primitives, and use FPGA block RAM for storage. If you are concerned about portability, or you just want to look at some VHDL code that does what you want, check the example below. It implements roughly the same circuit shown in the figure, and it will most likely be synthesized as distributed memory in the FPGA.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- Quad-port RAM with 2 read ports 2 write ports. The design uses 2 memory blocks
-- (MAIN_MEMORY and SHADOW_MEMORY) to allow for simultaneous writes. Port A writes to
-- main memory, Port B writes to shadow memory. On a read from either port, data is
-- read from the memory block that was most recently written at the given position.
entity quad_port_ram is
    generic (
        ADDRESS_WIDTH: natural := 5;
        DATA_WIDTH: natural := 32
    );
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;

        read_addr_a: in natural range 0 to 2**ADDRESS_WIDTH-1;
        read_data_a: out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        write_addr_a: in natural range 0 to 2**ADDRESS_WIDTH-1;
        write_data_a: in std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        write_enable_a: in std_logic;

        read_addr_b: in natural range 0 to 2**ADDRESS_WIDTH-1;
        read_data_b: out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        write_addr_b: in natural range 0 to 2**ADDRESS_WIDTH-1;
        write_data_b: in std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        write_enable_b: in std_logic
    );
end;

architecture rtl of quad_port_ram is

    type memory_type is (MAIN_MEMORY, SHADOW_MEMORY);
    type memory_type_array is array (natural range <>) of memory_type;

    -- Keep track of which memory has the most recently written data for each address
    signal most_recent_port_for_address: memory_type_array(0 to 2**ADDRESS_WIDTH-1);

    type memory_array is array (0 to 2**ADDRESS_WIDTH-1) of std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    type dual_memory_array is array (memory_type) of memory_array;

    -- Store the actual memory bits. Access like this:
    --   memory_data(memory_type)(address)(bit_position)
    signal memory_data: dual_memory_array;

    -- Auxiliary signals to decide where to read the data from (main or shadow)
    signal most_recent_port_for_addr_a, most_recent_port_for_addr_b: memory_type;
begin

    process (clock) begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then

            if write_enable_a then
                memory_data(MAIN_MEMORY)(write_addr_a) <= write_data_a;
                most_recent_port_for_address(write_addr_a) <= MAIN_MEMORY;
            end if;

            if write_enable_b then
                if (write_enable_a = '0') or (write_addr_a /= write_addr_b) then
                    memory_data(SHADOW_MEMORY)(write_addr_b) <= write_data_b;
                    most_recent_port_for_address(write_addr_b) <= SHADOW_MEMORY;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;

    end process;

    most_recent_port_for_addr_a <= most_recent_port_for_address(read_addr_a);
    most_recent_port_for_addr_b <= most_recent_port_for_address(read_addr_b);

    read_data_a <= memory_data(most_recent_port_for_addr_a)(read_addr_a);
    read_data_b <= memory_data(most_recent_port_for_addr_b)(read_addr_b);

end;
```